# Lock Google Apps script execution until text has been replaced

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I am currently using Google Apps script to undertake the following task in Google Docs:

- Open a Google Doc of a given Id
- Replace some text in the document
- Export the document to a PDF

The issue that I'm having is that the export process is happening before the text is updated in the body of the document. My question is:

**How do I halt the execution of exporting the Doc to PDF until the text has been replaced in the Doc?**

I've attached a simplified version of my code below:

```
function replaceTextAndExportToPDF() {
    var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

    // [Start block]

    // Clear the text surrounding "Apps Script", with or without text.
    var body = doc.getBody();
    body.replaceText("^.*Apps ?Script.*$", "Apps Script");

    // [End block -  Need to finish code inside this block before continuing]

    // Now export to PDF
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).getParents().next();
    var pdfBlob = doc.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
    parentFolder.createFile(pdfBlob)
}
```

I've tried testing with the [Lock Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/) but have limited knowledge of how it works and haven't had any success

Comment: I'm sorry. I misunderstood about your document. How about adding ``doc.saveAndClose()`` before ``var pdfBlob = doc.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');``? Document is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#saveandclose). If this was not directly solution for your situation, please tell me. I would like to think of other solution.

Comment: I'm using `DocumentApp` in my implementation not `SpreadsheetApp`. I couldn't see a similar `.flush()` method call in `DocumentApp`?

Comment: I updated my comment. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Bingo. The `.saveAndClose()` call did the trick. If you can add a response to my question, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I'm glad your issue was solved. I posted an answer by adding more information. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the issue can been resolved by using `saveAndClose()`.

#### Modification point :

Please modify as follows.

From :

```
var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).getParents().next();
var pdfBlob = doc.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
parentFolder.createFile(pdfBlob)
```

To :

```
var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).getParents().next();
doc.saveAndClose(); // Added
var pdfBlob = doc.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
parentFolder.createFile(pdfBlob)
```

#### Note :

- In the case of Document and Slides, it uses `saveAndClose()`.
- In the case of Spreadsheet, it uses `flush()`.

#### References :

- [Class Document saveAndClose()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#saveandclose)
- [Class Presentation saveAndClose()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#saveAndClose())
- [Class SpreadsheetApp flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)

### Added :

When the blob is retrieved from the Document using `getBlob()`, the mimeType of the blob is "application/pdf". So you can also use `var pdfBlob = doc.getBlob();` instead of `var pdfBlob = doc.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');`.

### Edit :

For example, you can retrieve the mimeType of the blob of `doc.getBlob()` by `Logger.log(doc.getBlob().getContentType())`. It shows `application/pdf`. I think that the default mimeType is `application/pdf` when the Google Docs are retrieved as a blob.

But you can retrieve other mimeTypes from Google Document. You can retrieve the formats which can be exported using `GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/about?fields=exportFormats&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`. The format for exporting Google Document is as follows.

```
"application/vnd.google-apps.document": [
 "application/rtf",
 "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text",
 "text/html",
 "application/pdf",
 "application/epub+zip",
 "application/zip",
 "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
 "text/plain"
],
```

From this object, Google Document cannot be exported as `application/vnd.google-apps.document`. It is considered that this is a specification.

Comment: Interestingly the `saveAndClose()` documentation mentions this: `Saves the current Document. Causes pending updates to be flushed and applied.` In my case, it appears that the changes were only being applied once the script had finished running as per the next comment `The saveAndClose() method is automatically invoked at the end of script execution, for each open Document.`

Comment: @ScottMcC Yes. So I think that when the pdf file is created, the replace was not reflected. Thank you for additional information. Also I added to my answer because I noticed a point.

Comment: I don't think `doc.getBlob()` returns as `application/pdf`? I'm pretty sure this returns as `application/vnd.google-apps.document`? https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types

Comment: @ScottMcC Thank you for replying. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?